# How to remove index from typeof object in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface, typescript2.0

using `[key: string]` will make my type accepting any key. I'm trying to avoid it because in some place I redefining types for property. Consider following.

```
interface IObject {
  [K: string]: number;
}

const base: IObject = {
  title: 0,
  age: 3
};
type StringValue<T> = { [K in keyof T]: string };  // <-- How to remove object index


const child: StringValue<typeof base> = {
  test: "" // <-- should not be possible
  title: '' // <-- this is OK
};
```

Comment: If `base` doesn't allow arbitrary keys but only `title` and `age`, then it's not an `IObject`. Why declare it as one? Separately, what's the purpose of `StringValue<T>`? *(not my downvote)*

Comment: updated by suggested naming. In simple example that's not an issue. However in complex structure like `base = { title: { value: '', valid: () => true }}` I want make sure to make a contract between values and another interface. `IObject { [K: string]: IProperty }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do that because `Base` looses the information about what was assigned to it once you explicitly type it as `IObject`. It's not the case that `Base` will have the index signature **and** the property names in it's type. The type of `Base` is `IObject` which is an index signature and nothing more.

My guess is you want to constrain `Base` to have only number properties, but you want to capture the actual type of the object literal you assign to it. Variables alone can't do this, you need to use an extra function. Functions can have type parameters that are constrained but inferred based on actual arguments.

```
interface IObject {
    [K: string]: number;
}
function createObject<T extends IObject>(o: T) {
    return o;
}
const base = createObject({
    title: 0,
    age: 3
});
type StringValue<T> = { [K in keyof T]: string };  // <-- How to remove object index


const child: StringValue<typeof base> = {
    test: "", // <-- error
    title: '', // <-- this is OK
    age: ""
};
```

Comment: Thats what I'm doing in a complex setup, however I run into issue on generic function ReturnType. So this doesn't compile `ReturnType<typeof createObject<T>>`. I guess that's another issue. Thanks for clarify what can be done here.

Comment: @EduardJacko you can't get the type of a generic function with type parameters applied. There is no syntax for that.